# Escaped unicode to unicode character in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, unicode, escaping, unicode-string

I get from a `NSURLConnection` a `NSData` object which I convert with

```
[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:[self urlData] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

to a `NSMutableString`. After some "revision" I display it in a `NSTextField`.
But when the response contains a more-than-utf8-string this is displayed:

[problem http://b5.s3.p.quickshareit.com/files/screenshot_466c60a6beaa2b390.png](http://b5.s3.p.quickshareit.com/files/screenshot_466c60a6beaa2b390.png)

This "&#x27A1" should be `one` unicode character. The char after `.ws/` seems to be an other problem which I would like to have solved. :)

It would be nice if there was a way without Carbon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "&#27a1" is an HTML/XML [character reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.3.1), and I don't think it's caused by any encoding/decoding you're doing in the code you've shown. That is, that almost certainly appears that way in the source.

It looks like [this page](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=8064367#8064367) (via [this page](http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-606180.html)) has some sample code at the bottom that might be useful to convert those to the correct characters: both a version using NSXMLParser, and one using CFXMLCreateStringByUnescapingEntities.